# Как поменять текст внутри div с помощью js?

Tags: javascript, html5

Я пытаюсь написать простую игру "города", и хочу что бы после того, как пользователь введет слово, оно отобразилось в div'e с id "last-word". Сейчас текст меняется на последнее введенное слово только после того, как закончится цикл. Можно ли сделать так, что бы текст менялся сразу же после arr.push(tmp); , не дожидаясь окончания цикла?

```js
if(confirm("Хотите сыграть в \"Города?\"") == true) {
 var firstround = true;
 let arr = [];
 let last;
 while(true) {
  var tmp = prompt("Введите город");
  last = arr[arr.length-1];
  if(!tmp) break;
  if(firstround == true) {
   firstround = false;
   arr.push(tmp);
   document.getElementById('last-word').innerHTML = arr[arr.length-1];
   continue;
  }
  if(last[last.length-1] == tmp[0]) {
   arr.push(tmp);
  }
  else break;
 }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>DZ</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<div id="last-word"></div>
<style type="text/css">
 h1 { display: flex; justify-content: center; }
 #last-word { color: red; display: flex; width: 50%; justify-content: center; font-size: 24px; padding-top: 200px; }
</style>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А для чего вы используете цикл? чего вы пытаетесь добится этим? не совсем понятно

Comment: @Alexander Vyshnyvetskyi скажите var это моветон когда есть let ?

Comment: @Leks я бы сказал что да. Ведь зачем комбинировать старый код с новым? Тоже самое что прицепить на брычку, колеса от феррари :D

Comment: @Leks let используется внутри текущего блока кода, а var - это глобальная директива.

Answer (score 0):

Покажу решение, может прочитав его, это вам поможет

```js
const cities = [];
const cityList = document.getElementById('city-list');

const startGame = () => {
  const cityName = prompt('Введите город', '');

  if (cityName === null) {
    alert('Вы отменили ввод');
    return;
  } else if (!cityName.length) {
    alert('Пустое поле не допустимо');
    startGame();
  } else if (cities.includes(cityName.toLocaleLowerCase())) {
    alert('Это имя уже было');
    startGame();
  } else if (cities.length && !cityName.toLocaleLowerCase().startsWith(cities[cities.length - 1].toLocaleLowerCase().substr(-1))) {
    alert('Не верное назавание');
    startGame();
  } else {
    const newRow = document.createElement('div');
    newRow.innerText = cityName;
    cities.push(cityName);
    cityList.appendChild(newRow);
    window.setTimeout(startGame);
  }
};

if (confirm('Хотите сыграть в "Города?"')) {
  startGame();
}
```

```html
<div id="city-list"></div>
```